# optional key is generated in firebase database

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database, option-type

This code is responsible  for uploading the text and and the time of the post  under an auto generated key of the logged in user  it is in the function didtappost in the first line

```
@IBOutlet weak var post: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var newpost: UITextView!


var databaseref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
var loggedinuser : AnyObject?
override func viewDidLoad()
{


    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.loggedinuser = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser
    newpost.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(30, 20, 20, 20)
    newpost.text = "what is new?"
    newpost.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
}
@IBAction func didtapcancel(_ sender: Any) {

    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)   
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textfield: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textfield.resignFirstResponder()
    return false
}

@IBAction func didtappost(_ sender: Any) {
    if(newpost.text.characters.count>0)
    {
        let key = databaseref.child("posts").childByAutoId().key

        let childupdates = ["/posts/\(self.loggedinuser!.uid)/\(key)/text ": newpost.text,"/posts/\(self.loggedinuser!.uid)/\(key)/time":"\(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)"
            ] as [String : Any]

        self.databaseref.updateChildValues(childupdates)
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
}
}
```

Comment: What is the issue actually?

Comment: an optional key is created in the firebase database why is it optional does optional mean nil?

Comment: can you share that optional key?and no it  does not mean nil for sure.

Comment: this is the key in the didtappost function let key = databaseref.child("posts").childByAutoId().key

Comment: That is your auto id because you have given the path as: databaseref.child("posts").childByAutoId().key.So an autoId has been generated there.

Comment: so how i can fix this optional issue? i just don't want the data to be like the in the firebase database optional(key)

Comment: if u dont want to add that autoId then just  remove :"childByAutoId()" from your database reference.